# How to add values in one array according to repeated values in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Suppose I have an array:

```
Values = np.array([0.221,0.35,25.9,54.212,0.0022])
Indices = np.array([22,10,11,22,10])
```

I would like to add elements of 'Values' together that share the same number in 'Indices'.

In other words, my desired outputs(s):

```
Total = np.array([0.221+54.212,0.35+0.002,25.9])
Index = np.array([22,10,11])
```

I've been trying to use np.unique to no avail. Can't quite figure this out!

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you? If it did, do consider accepting the one that worked best for you. More info on what it means and how to do so - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: yes! Sorry about that. Updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional arg `return_inverse` to get IDs based on uniqueness within `Indices` and then use those with `bincount` to get binned (ID based) summations and hence solve it like so -

```
Index,idx = np.unique(Indices, return_inverse=True)
Total = np.bincount(idx, Values)
```

Outputs for given sample -

```
In [32]: Index
Out[32]: array([10, 11, 22])

In [33]: Total
Out[33]: array([ 0.3522, 25.9   , 54.433 ])
```

Alternatively, we can use `pandas.factorize` to get the unique IDs and then bincount as shown earlier. So, the first step could be replaced by something like this -

```
import pandas as pd

idx,Index = pd.factorize(Indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to consider using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: pd.DataFrame({'Values': Values, 'Indices': Indices}).groupby('Indices').agg(sum)
Out[15]: 
          Values
Indices         
10        0.3522
11       25.9000
22       54.4330
```

This should be self-explanatory, though it doesn't preserve the order of indices (it's not entirely clear from the question whether you care about that).